# Implementing verification method to allow only String input in Java

Tags: java, validation

Im trying to implement a method to verify and only allow string input to be stored by the program. Found the Integer.parseInt() method and reversed it so that upon catching exception > it returns and shows no error the user prompting user has entered the correct input. However, it so happens that if input is a mix of String and integers, NumberFormatException is not thrown. or is it? Is there another method to achieve above verification without using String.contains() and comparing to array of all integers ({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0})?
below is the snippet of the code for the method to validate string and the driver class which calls the method.
-validation method

```
public static boolean validateName(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(name);
            System.out.println("Kindly refrain from entering numbers into name field");
            System.out.println("Only characters and symbols allowed in name");
            return false;
            //error flagged as name only accepts character and symbol
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {            
            return true;
        }
    }
```

driver class calling for method validateName()

```
...
        //name entry and validation
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
            name=input.nextLine();
            flag=validateName(name); 
        }
        while(!flag);
...
```

Comment: You could use a *regular expression*.

Comment: Note, by the way, that you're breaking the mold with your method setup: Normally, a method called `verify` either returns `void`, does nothing on success, and throws an exception if the input isn't valid, or, it returns `true` if valid, `false` if invalid. Also, in that second case they are generally called `isValidName`, not `verifyName`. You've gone for the exotic option of returning `true` to indicate failure. I strongly suggest you fix that. When in Rome, and all that.

Comment: i suggest you look into String.matches() and regular expressions.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Comment: @rzwitserloot thx 4 the input. Will change it up to suit the norm ^^

Comment: @JanezKuhar Actually I am already incorporating matches and regex into the email verification part of this program but still quite unfamiliar with regex. Not to mention coming up with an expression which has spaces in between first name and last name and not allowing integers to be a valid input. Will look back into regex tho. Thx

Comment: @BlinkCPTL You could try something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/oIf5RH/1) then.

Comment: @Janezkuhar nice~~ thx this really helps with experimenting =D